# Android AppWidget: Method callback on instance created?

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

There doesn't seem to be a method for AppWidgetProviders that gets called every time an instance of the widget gets created. Anyone know if there is a way to do this? Something similar to onDelete() but for creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didnt set a configuration activity, onUpdate will be called when a new app widget is created.

If you did set a configuration activity, onUpdate **won't** be called when a new app widget is created, but only on updates.

Note that reading documentation always helps, especially when messing with stuff like app widgets - alot of mistakes lay waiting for you. Learn from my mistake :(